# Ruby on Rails using Data Table based on Rails Cast #340, Server Side processing JSON format error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, datatables

I think is a bug somewhere which is causing this problem for me since months already.
I am coding based on the Rails Cast #340 for using data tables with server side processing.
Below is the code I am using, one section, I have to more all with same error.
I know that was debated already 1 million times,I fetched all articles written on this topic, I tried almost everything but nothing worked for me to fix this.

From the main menu when clicking on the Table link I am getting:

DataTables warning (table id = 'allmeasurementstable'): DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error.

The class code is below:

class MeasurementsDatatable
      delegate :params, :h, :link_to, :number_to_currency, :number_with_precision, to: :@view

```
  def initialize(view)
    @view = view
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      sEcho: params[:sEcho].to_i,
      iTotalRecords: Measurement.count,
      iTotalDisplayRecords: records_m.total_entries,
      aaData: data
    }
  end

private

  def data
    @records = records_m
    @records.to_a.map do |record|
      [
          record.scheduled_reading_date,
          record.inst_type,
          link_to(record.inst_id, record), #record.inst_id,
          record.scheduled_reading,
          record.first_or_single_reading_taken,
          record.first_or_single_reading_taken_date,
          record.first_or_single_reading_not_taken_reason,
          record.second_reading_taken,
          record.second_reading_taken_date,
          record.second_reading_not_taken_reason,
          record.third_reading_taken,
          record.third_reading_taken_date,
          record.third_reading_not_taken_reason,
          record.last_updated_by
      ]
    end
  end

  def records_m
    @records ||= fetch_records
  end

  def fetch_records
    #looks like .all is not necessary like in the case of the list, see controller
    if params[:sSearch].present?
      @records = Measurement.order("#{sort_column}")
                  .where("
                    '%'||scheduled_reading_date||'%' LIKE :search
                    or upper(inst_type) LIKE upper(:search)
                    or (upper(inst_id) LIKE upper(:search) 
                    or upper(scheduled_reading) LIKE upper(:search)
                    or upper(first_or_single_reading_taken) LIKE upper(:search)
                    or '%'||first_or_single_reading_taken_date||'%' LIKE :search
                    or upper(first_or_single_reading_not_taken_reason) LIKE upper(:search)
                    or upper(second_reading_taken) LIKE upper(:search)
                    or '%'||second_reading_taken_date||'%' LIKE :search
                    or upper(second_reading_not_taken_reason) LIKE upper(:search)
                    or upper(third_reading_taken) LIKE upper(:search)
                    or '%'||third_reading_taken_date||'%' LIKE :search
                    or upper(third_reading_not_taken_reason) LIKE upper(:search)
                    or upper(last_updated_by) LIKE upper(:search)
                    )", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
    else
      if params[:iSortCol_0].present?
        @records = Measurement.all.order("#{sort_column}")
      else
        @records = Measurement.all
      end
    end
    @records = @records.page(page).per_page(per_page)
  end

  def page
    params[:iDisplayStart].to_i/per_page + 1
  end

  def per_page
    params[:iDisplayLength].to_i > 0 ? params[:iDisplayLength].to_i : 10
  end

  def sort_column
    columns = %w[scheduled_reading_date inst_type inst_id scheduled_reading 
      first_or_single_reading_taken first_or_single_reading_taken_date first_or_single_reading_not_taken_reason 
      second_reading_taken second_reading_taken_date second_reading_not_taken_reason  
      third_reading_taken third_reading_taken_date third_reading_not_taken_reason
      last_updated_by]
    s = columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i] + " " + sort_direction(:sSortDir_0)
    if params[:iSortCol_1].present?
      s = s + "," + columns[params[:iSortCol_1].to_i] + " " + sort_direction(:sSortDir_1)
    end
    if params[:iSortCol_2].present?
      s = s + "," + columns[params[:iSortCol_2].to_i] + " " + sort_direction(:sSortDir_2)
    end
    if params[:iSortCol_3].present?
      s = s + "," + columns[params[:iSortCol_3].to_i] + " " + sort_direction(:sSortDir_3)
    end
    if params[:iSortCol_4].present?
      s = s + "," + columns[params[:iSortCol_4].to_i] + " " + sort_direction(:sSortDir_4)
    end
    s
  end

  def sort_direction (n)
    params[n] == "desc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  end 
end
```

The html code is here:

```
<% provide(:title, 'All Measurements') %>

<% if signed_in? %>

    <h3>
        All Measurements from: <%=@min_date%> to: <%=@max_date%> Records: <%=@count%>
    </h3>

    <p>
        <%= link_to "List view", measurements_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary" %>
    </p>

    <table id="allmeasurementstable" class="display table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive table-hover" data-source="<%= measurements_datatable_url(format: "json") %>">
        <thead style="background-color: #bbbbbb;">
            <tr>
                <th>Scheduled Reading Date</th>
                <th>Instrument Type</th>
                <th>Instrument ID</th>
                <th>Scheduled Readings</th>
                <th>First or Single Reading Taken</th>
                <th>First or Single Reading Taken Date</th>
                <th>First or Single Reading Not Taken Reason</th>
                <th>Second Reading Taken</th>
                <th>Second Reading Taken Date</th>
                <th>Second Reading Not Taken Reason</th>
                <th>Third Reading Taken</th>
                <th>Third Reading Taken Date</th>
                <th>Third Reading Not Taken Reason</th>
                <th>Last Updated by</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<% else %>
    <%= render 'instruments/unsigned' %>
<% end %>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#allmeasurementstable').dataTable({
        bJQueryUI: true,
        bDeferRender: true,
        bStateSave: true,
        bProcessing: true,
        bServerSide: true,
        sAjaxSource: $('#measurements_datatable_url').data('source')
    }).fnSort( [ [0,'desc'],[2,'asc'] ] );
  } );
</script>
```

The controller code is here (only the method for the table):

```
  def allmeasurementstable
    @min_date = Measurement.minimum(:scheduled_reading_date)
    @max_date = Measurement.maximum(:scheduled_reading_date)
    @count    = Measurement.count
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {
        render json: MeasurementsDatatable.new(view_context) 
      }
    end
  end
```

Comment: When switching between tables the header is displayed correctly but the body, the rows are from the previous tables. Can't understand why the JSON is not created new and getting the right data from the right table to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, moved to another version of Data Tables, last compiled and posted on data tables web site at the end of July 2014.